# Can`t load JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to test a simple JavaScript function in ASP.NET.

**Movies/Index.cshtml**

```
<!-- My local JavaScript File -->
<script src="~/Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="button" id="getPeople" value="Get People"/>
<ul id="people_list"/>
```

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**/Scripts/JavaScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{

});

$('#getPeople').click(function () 
{
    alert("getPeople");
}
```

I press the button but no alert appears. Why?

Comment: Because you are loading your javascript file before the `#getPeople` element, your click handler needs to be _within_ the doc.ready block. Not after it. Is  the unclosed click handler a copy-paste error or your actual code?

Comment: Is the click handler really outside of ready handler? If so, put it inside and that should do it

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {

    //Populate Contact
    //LoadContacts();

    $('#getPeople').click(function () {
        alert("getPeople");
});


This not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

- to import jQuery first (before importing `/Scripts/JavaScript.js`)
- to add click handler inside document's ready event.

Check the output of your composed page (for example Developer tools in the browser), if you are uncertain.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getPeople').click(function () {
        alert("getPeople");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The click handler of `'#getPeople'` should be inside `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $('#getPeople').click(function () 
    {
        alert("getPeople");
    }
});
```